# TTF/Font file seen as error in Jetpack Compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a custom font, I downloaded the "Poppins" font and pasted the TTF files into the freshly made "font" folder and they have a red line under them, presumably trying to indicate that there is a problem with them. The "font" folder I made is located in java/res/font.

I tried to google the issue but I could not find anything about this. May you help me? I will attach a photo of the hierarchy and how they look. Android Studio doesn't give any info on what that may be. Thanks for looking into this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAWHe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capital letters and `-` chars are not allowed in resource file names. Rename the files to all lowercase, and you can replace the `-` with underscore `_`.